# Getting length\count of items in DynamicJson array

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

I am getting one json string which I am converting into dynamic object by using [DynamicJson](https://dynamicjson.codeplex.com/) library. Though I am getting an array back, I am not able to get the count/length property of this array.

See the below image for more information.

I have tried, C`ount, Length & length` properties. All these properties are not available. How can I get count for a DynamicJson array ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Though I am not able to get the length\count of the array, I am now using foreach loop to get the data:

```
var dynJson = DynamicJson.Parse(result);
            var jarr = dynJson.results.docs;
            foreach (var item in jarr)
            {
                var v = item[attribute];

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the library supports casting *at least* to `T[]` and `List<T>`, so you can:

```
var json = DynamicJson.Parse(@"{""foo"": [1, 2, 3] }");
int[] arr = json.foo;
int length = arr.Length;
```

or

```
List<int> lst = json.foo;
int length2 = lst.Count;
```

Note that you can even cast to `object[]` or `List<object>`!

More complex example:

```
var json = DynamicJson.Parse(@"{""foo"": [{ ""bar"": 5 }, 2, 3] }");
dynamic[] arr = json.foo;
int length = arr.Length;

List<dynamic> lst = json.foo;
int length2 = lst.Count;

int bar1 = (int)json.foo[0].bar;
int bar2 = (int)arr[0].bar;
//int bar3 = (int)lst[0].bar; // doesn't work!
```

Note that there seems to be at least a bug with the `List<>` handling.